# Making the most of dual channel DDR2: how do I arrange the sticks?

Tags: memory, ddr2, dual-channel

I've searched online, but I can't find anything definitive that will put me at ease. I turn to superuser.

This is how I have the RAM sticks arranged now:

[image]

To make the most of the RAM and the dual channel capability, it occurred to me that perhaps I have the sticks arranged incorrectly. Should I move the stick in the DDR2_2 slot one over--to the adjacent, red slot?

I appreciate any suggestions. (BTW, can something in BIOS tell me whether I'm running at "optimal" memory speeds??)

edit: I'm running Windows XP SP3, 32-bit. Thanks.

edit2: I apologize for not specifying that the mobo is a Gigabyte GA-M720-US3.

edit3: The comments and answers here have one thing in common: RTM. Yes, I completely forgot I had it; and in my eagerness to put the system together I must have overlooked the page discussing the RAM. Cause it's just RAM, right!?

Thanks again to all!

Comment: Use CPU-z, and switch to the memory tab to confirm you're running in Dual channel mode.

Comment: Do you have your motherboard manual?  It will specify in there.  What kind of motherboard is it?  You might be able to find it on the internet.

Comment: I could answer this with the three letters "RTM" but since 15 letters are required I have to type a whole sentence.  What is your motherboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't list what your mobo is I took all the little details off of it that I could see to narrow the search.  This is from page 16 of the manual for a Gigabyte GA-MA790GP-UD4H, a motherboard that (like yours) has a AM3/AM2+/AM2 socket, 4 DIMM slots capable of running 1200+ memory, uses HT3.0, and has at least one PCI-E x16 slot.  The link for that manual is [here](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-ma790gp-ud4h_e.pdf).  As you can see from the picture below (if your motherboard is like this one, which I believe it is) you need to put your RAM in the two slots closest to the processor, which is what you have already done.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your reply--it has put me at ease. The mobo is actually GA-M720-US3. Nice work btw.

Comment: Your motherboard is unusual. This is the reverse of the way it is usually done.

Comment: *> Your motherboard is unusual. This is the reverse of the way it is usually done.* Gigabyte did it right. This is the reverse of the wrong way that is usually done—for some reason. `:-|`